# Using Apache Benchmark to test performace CPU load of 55

Tags: mysql, performance, load-balancing

I was doing a test to see what kind of performance to expect from my server. I put together a few PHP pages that each posts 500 records in JSON to an api endpoint that parses it for database insertion.

Using Apache Benchmark I had 2 different servers each hitting different pages with 30 concurrent sessions to see what happened. The server has the following stats:

```
2X  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz (8 core, 16 thread each)
96GB DDR3
PCI SSD
```

Here is a sample of the top command:

```
 4904 mysql     20   0 10.916g 1.634g  20300 S 186.0  1.7  80:58.56 mysqld                                                                                                                                                        
 9098 root      20   0  342652  45288  22504 R 100.0  0.0   0:08.12 php7.0                                                                                                                                                        
 9058 www-data  20   0  473720  53932  21612 S  31.9  0.1   0:09.95 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9051 www-data  20   0  474024  54484  21880 S  31.6  0.1   0:09.64 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7287 www-data  20   0  474528  58100  25056 S  31.2  0.1   2:09.70 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7466 www-data  20   0  474668  56876  23724 S  30.6  0.1   1:23.09 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7689 www-data  20   0  474672  56972  23832 S  30.2  0.1   1:36.35 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9061 www-data  20   0  473720  53928  21604 S  30.2  0.1   0:09.68 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7470 www-data  20   0  472532  55028  23876 S  28.2  0.1   1:50.36 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7497 www-data  20   0  472004  52788  22108 S  27.9  0.1   2:01.92 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9056 www-data  20   0  471672  51860  21588 R  27.6  0.1   0:09.10 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7662 www-data  20   0  472428  53236  22344 S  27.2  0.1   1:17.66 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7073 www-data  20   0  472180  52872  22152 S  26.6  0.1   2:27.52 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7531 www-data  20   0  472020  52988  22288 S  26.6  0.1   1:59.16 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7691 www-data  20   0  472520  54976  23844 S  26.2  0.1   1:35.05 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7457 www-data  20   0  472036  52708  22072 S  25.9  0.1   1:28.16 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7516 www-data  20   0  475904  58368  26900 S  25.9  0.1   1:56.30 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7690 www-data  20   0  472512  55036  23896 S  25.9  0.1   1:20.92 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7118 www-data  20   0  472004  52836  22152 S  25.6  0.1   2:47.01 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9050 www-data  20   0  473744  54236  21824 S  24.9  0.1   0:09.22 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9046 www-data  20   0  473720  53944  21620 S  24.6  0.1   0:08.97 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7534 www-data  20   0  472004  52836  22176 S  23.9  0.1   1:43.85 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9060 www-data  20   0  473720  53944  21620 S  23.9  0.1   0:08.67 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7285 www-data  20   0  472532  53972  22960 S  23.6  0.1   1:52.67 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9055 www-data  20   0  473720  54044  21716 S  23.6  0.1   0:08.67 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7512 www-data  20   0  472428  53112  22176 S  23.3  0.1   1:41.66 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9052 www-data  20   0  473720  53928  21604 S  23.3  0.1   0:08.67 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9053 www-data  20   0  471688  52268  21888 S  23.3  0.1   0:08.24 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7122 www-data  20   0  472004  52908  22240 S  22.9  0.1   2:08.46 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 9057 www-data  20   0  471696  52096  21736 S  22.9  0.1   0:08.26 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7283 www-data  20   0  472012  52888  22224 S  22.6  0.1   2:05.82 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7535 www-data  20   0  472632  55088  23888 S  21.6  0.1   1:59.44 apache2                                                                                                                                                       
 7294 www-data  20   0  757440 342200  26248 S   7.0  0.3   2:00.95 apache2
```

Unsurprisingly we see lots of apache sessions. I was surprised however when the server load went to 55 and yet the website was as responsive as ever while navigating. I thought that with 2 CPUs with 16 threads each then 32 would have been maxed out, but I guess with hyperthreading it will go to 64 before I will see lag.

I know MySQL has some multithreading built in, so I shouldn't worry that its reported utilization is at 186% from my understanding, but at what point should I look at the CPU utilization of the MySQL instance and start to consider sharding or other load balancing considerations?

I can easily offload the apache part of the processing to additional servers and all have them tie in to the same MySQL server when needed, so I am primarily concerned about the MySQL utilization so I can watch it for early signs it will need attention.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarks are often designed to find the "breaking point".  You are extremely unlikely to have 32 users active *simultaneously*.  Work on how many `INSERTs` you need in an hour.  Your 32 users will do their thing, then be done for the day.  This averages out to very few inserts/hour.

As for "go to 64 before lag", that depends a lot on what version of MySQL.  5.7 might be able to handle 64 *active* users before InnoDB stumbles over itself.  5.0 would have trouble at 4 or 8.

It would help if you completely turn off the Query cache: `query_cache_type = 0` and `query_cache_size = 0`.  The QC is a choke point.

I am used to having *several* Apache servers (each in its own server) talking to a *few* MySQL Slaves.  The main point of hassle came when *Apache* allowed too many web pages to start up and start hitting more than the above threshold for MySQL multithreading.  It turns out to be better to cut back on the number of threads *in Apache*.

Where the correct number is depends on the web code, the queries, etc.